# NSString is wiped when the segue finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, storyboard

Ive been working on updating an xcode project to storyboard style and having changed the three views in the old xcode xib to three view controllers on the new storyboard style im having a problem with the string i created to pass the data from one view controller to the other, when i switch to the third view controller to get some more info, the date of birth, the first label with the initial piece of data goes blank.

I have three view controllers.  The first is where i have the strings *concentrationString and *DOBString.  This is where the data that is selected on the other views is displayed.

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *concentrationlabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *DOBlabel;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *concentrationString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DOBString;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize concentrationString, DOBString;

...


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     concentrationlabel.text = concentrationString;
     DOBlabel.text = DOBString;

...
```

The SecondViewController.m has several buttons for medications that tells the first view controller what value to put into the concentration label using the prepareForSegue stuff i found

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

...

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Adrenaline"]) {
        NSString *concentrationString = @"Adrenaline";
        FirstViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.concentrationString = concentrationString; }


    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Morphine"]) {
        NSString *concentrationString = @"Morphine";
        FirstViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.concentrationString = concentrationString; }
```

and it updated the label on the first view with either "Adrenaline" or "Morphine" depending on which button was clicked.

When the user goes to the ThirdViewController.m to select the patients date of birth from a picker and i use the prepareForSegue method to send that value back, the first label goes blank, although i did not specify a change to concentrationString

```
#import "DOBViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface DOBViewController ()

@end

@implementation DOBViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    [picker setDate:now animated:YES];
    [DOBset setTitle:@"Date of birth" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)displayDate:(id)sender {
//  NSDate * selected = [picker date];
//  NSString * date = [selected description];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMMM-yyy"]; //24hr time format
    NSString *dateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
    [DOBset setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DOB"]) {
        NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMMM-yyy"]; //24hr time format
        NSString *DOBString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
        FirstViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.DOBString = DOBString;
    }
}

@end
```

How should i work this?
Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Kurt.

Comment: First, variables should start with a lowercase letter. Second, remove the iVars (use properties in their place). Third, remove the `@synthesize` lines. These are no longer needed as Xcode auto synthesizes them. Fourth, access the properties using `self.blah`.

Comment: Your question is not related to xcode.

Comment: What exactly is your navigation tree here? FirstVC calls (segues to) SecondVC and that segues to ThridVC (the DOB-VC) and that segues to FirstVC? If so then you are likely to insanciate a second instance of FirstVC where all properties are initialized with zero or nil.

Comment: The navigation is the first page has lots of labels and buttons on it, the first button take you to the second view controller where the user picks a value, then it goes back to the first page.  Then they click the second button and they go to the third page and pick another value and it goes back to the first page but the first value they picked from the seond page disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your FirstViewController like this...

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *concentrationString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dOBString;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

// anything that isn't accessed from outside this class should be
// in the private category extension.
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *concentrationLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *dOBLabel;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.concentrationLabel.text = self.concentrationString;
     self.dOBLabel.text = self.dOBString;
}
...
```

I think you are confusing the program with ivars and properties that are not actually pointing to the same thing.

When you use a property *always refer to it using `self.property`. (Unless in the getter, setter or constructor where you should use `_property`).

By changing the code this way you should find it works.

Also, variable names start with a lowercase letter and use camel case.

i.e. DOBlabel is not OK... dOBLabel is OK.
concentrationlabel is not OK... concentrationLabel is OK.

Comment: Thankyou for the fast reply Fogmeister.  I made your changes, put self in front and strong in the fvc.h and weak property in the fvc.m but the concentrationLabel label still goes blank after they go to the third view controller and pick the date of birth then go back to the first

Comment: How are you going back to the first view controller?

Comment: in the second page = -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Adrenaline"]) {
        NSString *concentrationString = @"Adrenaline";
        FirstViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.concentrationString = concentrationString; }

Comment: I checked all the caps and the concentrationLabel still goes blank after the user returns from the third view. it still disappears

Comment: Ah, that's your problem. You can't use a segue to go backwards. To go back you have to use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` or something like this. What you are doing is creating a new instance of FirstViewController (like WizKid1490 said).

Comment: You are best using delegation for this.

Comment: Yeah i guess i am creating a new first view and thats why it goes blank.  will [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; do what i need it to do? or  i'll start looking up delegation

Comment: It will pop back to the first controller. You can use delegation to pass the selected information (i.e. the DOB) back to the first view controller. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: Thanks I found some info and this tutorial to redesign the app. http://youtube.com/watch?v=XZWT0IV8FrI&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXZWT0IV8FrI

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this is not working is because you are creating two different objects for the same view Controller(namely 1st view controller). In order to get the changes from both controllers visible in the first controller you have to get the same reference of the first view controller in both the controllers.

It can be done by creating an IBOutlet for the first view controller in the AppDelegate class as a property
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet FirstViewController *firstViewController;

and then using the code in both classes by importing AppDelegate.h:

```
   AppDelegate *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   FirstViewController *vc=(FirstViewController *)app.firstViewController;
   vc=[[segue destinationViewController];

Now vc will refer to the same class rather than two different objects of the FirstViewController and then you can see the changes done together.
```

Comment: Where is this happening?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help I dont thinks its as simple as i thought

Comment: +1 Good spot, I didn't spot that he is using a segue from Third to First.

Comment: I could use a bit of help putting this in if its going to work.  Where do i put @property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet FirstViewController *firstViewController; and AppDelegate *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   FirstViewController *vc=(FirstViewController *)app.firstViewController;
   vc=[[segue destinationViewController];

Comment: Is the first View controller the view defined in the AppDelegate.h class?